# How to put my app icon on locked screen in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-widget, android-wake-lock

I am developing a security app. So its necessary for me to put it on lock screen. Is there a way to put it on lock screen? so that user can interact directly when needed.

Answer (score 1):

For devices with lockscreens that support app widgets, you can [write an app widget that can be placed on the lockscreen](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#lockscreen).